# DataTables automatically set export title

Tags: jquery, datatables

I got the following .js file which is called on each page of my website and automatically transforms tables to DataTables:

```
$.extend( $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "buttons": [
        $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
            }
        } ),
        $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            orientation: 'landscape',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
            }
        } ),
        $.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
            extend: 'print',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible'
            },
            orientation: 'landscape'
        } )
    ]
} );

//Render datatables
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.data-table').length !== 0)
    {
        $('.data-table').DataTable();
    }
});
```

When I export a table (i.e. excelHtml5, pdfHtml5 or print), I want the exported document's title to display the table's **data-exporttitle** attribute if the table has such attribute, or else display a default value. Currently and by default, the title displays the page header title.

How can the above script be modified in order to achieve this?

If this info is of any help, some pages on my website contain more than one table.

My first reflex was to add the following "title" line of code in each extend function, but it doesn't work:

```
$.extend( true, {}, buttonCommon, {
    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
    orientation: 'landscape',
    title: $(this).data("export-title")
} ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `buttons.init` in the `buttonCommon` literal. The table reference is a little bit hidden in the params, but it works :

```
var buttonCommon = {
  init: function(dt, node, config) {
    var table = dt.table().context[0].nTable;
    if (table) config.title = $(table).data('export-title')
  },
  title: 'default title'
};
```

Now the button exports will have the same `title` as their associated tables `data-export-title` attribute.

---

Usage `<table id="example" data-export-title="test">`

demo **https://jsfiddle.net/d72vmj2h/1/**

Comment: I tried the code and it does not work. I keep seeing "default title" as the exported document title. It seems that this.title does not change the title property. How can this be solved?

Comment: @AdamStrudwick See update, have added a working fiddle.  Be sure you have a `data-export-title` attribute and use a recent version of the buttons library.

Comment: I tried your fiddle and see "default title" as a title when clicking pdf and print. I tried both with Google Chrome and Firefox. Am I doing something wrong? Could it be a scope issue here within the function?

Comment: @AdamStrudwick, Funny. On my ubuntu chromium it works, tried on a macbook with chrome, the title is never updated.  I will look into why this happens. Weird, actually. As `this` is treated different.

Comment: @AdamStrudwick Got it:  Set `config title` instead.  Ideally also the "correct" approach. It solved the issue on the mac chrome. BTW, you should define filename also, to avoid the export get the same name as the title. Have updated the fiddle.